# Webdriver(Selenium2) - How to make selenium operate elements without wating for connecting to external AD links?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

**Environment:**
- Selenium 2.39 Standalone Server
- PHP 5.4.11
- PHPUnit 3.7.28
- Chrome V31 & ChromeDriver v2.7

I'm testing a website,which invokes a lot of Advertisement Systems,such as Google AD.
 
The browser takes a lot of time to connect to external AD links , even all the elements of the page has already been loaded.

If my internet network was not fast when I ran my tests on a webpage, 
Selenium would wait for a very long time ,since the AD links responsed slowly.

Under this condition ,Selenium usually waits for over 60 seconds, and throws a timeout exception.

I'm not sure how Senelium works, but it seems that Selenium has to wait for a sign of webpage's full loading, then pulls the DOM to find elements.

I want to make selenium operate elements without waiting for connectiong to external AD links.
Is there a way to do that ? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use a chrome extension such as Adblock to block all ads. Set it on the driver using [ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

Comment: thanks @Faiz but selenium launchs chrome with no extension ,and it will be complex if i set a chrome profile in the test scrpits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a simple solution for my condition.

I decide to block these Ad requests and tried some firewall and proxy softwares,for example,
comodo,privatefirewall, etc. 
comodo is too heavy and  complex ,privatefirewall doesn't support wildcards, and firewall would interrupt tests. 
At last I choosed a proxy software [CCproxy](http://download.cnet.com/CCProxy/3000-2651_4-10062250.html). Trial Version is enough.
I create a rule for localhost ,to make it can request my test website domain only, and all other requests are rejected.

Running a test costs about 1-2 minutes　before and only 30 seconds now ,it's apparently more stable and fast without connecting to the useless Ad links.

Here're configuration steps:
1.launch CCproxy with Administor privilege( you should set it using Adminisrator in the file property)
2.click Options, select AutoStartup,select AutoDetected for Local IP Address. click OK.
3.create a txt file ,input your domains,like " *.rong360.com*;*.rong360.*; "
4.click Account, select PermitOnly for Permit Category;
  click New, input 127.0.0.1 for IP Address/Range;
  select WebFilter,click the E button at right side to create a filter;
  click the ... button,select the text file you create at Step3,
  select PermittedSites. click OK
  click OK.
5.click OK to return to the main UI of CCproxy.
6.launch IE and config the local  proxy with 127.0.0.1:808
  other browsers will use this config automatically too.

now you can run the tests again , you'll feel better if have same condition :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you could make use of a proxy. [Browsermob](http://bmp.lightbody.net/) integrates well with selenium, very easy to use it:

```
// start the proxy
ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(4444);
server.start();

// get the Selenium proxy object
Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy();

// This line will automatically return http.200 for any request going to google analytics
server.blacklistRequests("https?://.*\\.google-analytics\\.com/.*", 200);

// configure it as a desired capability
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

// start the browser up
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

---

> I'm not sure how Senelium works, but it seems that Selenium has to
>   wait for a sign of webpage's full loading, then pulls the DOM to find
>   elements.

It is pretty much like this. The default [loading strategy](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webdriver/raw-file/tip/webdriver-spec.html#page-load-strategies-1) is "NORMAL" which means:

> NORMAL of type DOMString
>       The remote end MUST wait until the "document.readyState" of the frame currently handling commands equals "complete", or there are no
>   more outstanding network requests other than XMLHttpRequests.

Comment: Thank you!@Erki M  I'll do some experiments and report the result later.

Comment: Sorry i did't post my environment , I'm using phpunit/phpunit-selenium  while Browsermob is for Java. But I think  you point out the right way to resolve this problem. I'm trying to find something similar for PHP now . And Thanks for your explanation of the loading strategy :)

Comment: I believe this PHPBrowserMobProxy would solve my problem.@Erki M Thank u very much.

Comment: After trying PHPBrowserMobProxy for a moment, I found that it's lack of a commponent called Request of  which i couldn't find the download link. And I felt it's a little complicated,  then  turned to another way. I tried several firewall or proxy softwares to block    and finally choosed [CCproxy](http://download.cnet.com/CCProxy/3000-2651_4-10062250.html) as the solution. It does work.  @Erkis  Your answer is still very oriented for me and useful for Java users