# HTTP Proxy or Firewall - I want to find a light http-proxy software,which can be set a whitelist and return 500 to all other links

Tags: http, proxy

I'm testing a webpage, which would connect some external Links .
I don't want the page to  take too much time to connect them .

So is there any light http-proxy or firewall  software, it can be set a white list, 
and return 500 directly to all other links that are not in the white list.
Thanks.  better if it supports https

I am working with PHP/PHPunit/Win7

Answer (score 0):

**duplicate** with another question of mine:
[Webdriver(Selenium2) - How to make selenium operate elements without wating for connecting to external AD links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218735/webdriverselenium2-how-to-make-selenium-operate-elements-without-wating-for)

I finally found a simple solution for my condition.

I want to block these Ad requests and tried some firewall and proxy softwares,for example,
comodo,privatefirewall, etc. 
comodo is too heavy and  complex ,privatefirewall doesn't support wildcards, and firewall would interrupt tests. 
At last I choosed a proxy software [CCproxy](http://download.cnet.com/CCProxy/3000-2651_4-10062250.html).
I create a rule for localhost ,to make it can request my test website domain only, and all other requests are rejected.

Running a test costs about 1-2 minutes　before and only 30 seconds now ,it's apparently more stable and fast without connecting to the useless Ad links.

Here're configuration steps:
1.launch CCproxy with Administor privilege( you should set it using Adminisrator in the file property)
2.click Options, select AutoStartup,select AutoDetected for Local IP Address. click OK.
3.create a txt file ,input your domains,like "*.rong360.com*;*.rong360.*;"
4.click Account, select PermitOnly for Permit Category;
  click New, input 127.0.0.1 for IP Address/Range;
  select WebFilter,click the E button at right side to create a filter;
  click the ... button,select the text file you create at Step3,
  select PermittedSites. click OK
  click OK.
5.click OK to return to the main UI of CCproxy.
6.launch IE and config the local  proxy with 127.0.0.1:808

now you can run the tests again , you'll feel better if have same condition :)